# updating a user control in an asp.net update panel (based upon action in another user control)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

I have 2 Update Panels, as shown below, on an aspx page. The aspx page uses a UserControl element, which  implements a repeater with a list of page numbers displayed on it. There are 2 lists of page numbers, say L1 ans L2, one  at the top of the page and one at the bottom. (Hence, the 2 User Controls, RevPaging1 and RevPaging2 on the  aspx page).

```
<%@ Register Src="../Controls/UseControl.ascx" TagName="UserControl" TagPrefix="uc1" %>

 <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>

        <div id="Div1" class="paging" runat="server" visible="false">
            <uc1:UserControl id="RevPaging1" runat="server" ShowResult="false">
            </uc1:UserControl>          
        </div>

         </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>   

    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel2" UpdateMode="Conditional">

         <ContentTemplate>

            <div id="Div2" class="paging" runat="server" visible="false">
                    <uc1:UserControl id="RevPaging2" runat="server" ShowResult="false">
                    </uc1:UserControl>          
            </div>          

       </ContentTemplate>

    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Question: How do I make sure that when I click on any page number on  "RevPaging1"
      , the page number is automatically updated on "RevPaging2" to the same 
          number that i selected on RevPaging1(one that I did not click on) and similarly,    when I click on any page number on  "RevPaging2" the page number is automatically updated on "RevPaging1" (one that I did not click on).

Following is the implementation of the UserControl (which is declared twice inside the the 2 
update panels above).

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" 
    CodeBehind="UserControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="Namespace.UserControl" %>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="left">
                <p class="button2Left"></p>
                    <asp:Button ID="btPreviousPage" runat="server" cssclass="button2" 
                                 OnClick="btPreviousPage_Click" Text="Previous Page" />
                <p class="button2Right"></p>
            </td>
            <td class="middle">
            <asp:Repeater ID="pageNumbers" runat="server" OnItemCommand="pageNumbers_ItemCommand">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <ul>This is the header template</ul>
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <li class='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"PCssClass")%>'>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" CommandName="prefixLink" 
                                        CommandArgument='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"PText")%>' 
                                        runat="server" 
                                        Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"PText")%>' />
                    </li>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                      <ul>This is the footer template</ul>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
            </td>

            <td class="right">
                <p class="button2Left"></p>
                    <asp:Button ID="btNextPage" cssclass="button2" runat="server" OnClick="btNextPage_Click" Text="Next Page" />
                <p class="button2Right"></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! When posting questions like this that have a more general form, its a good idea to distill the code down to the relevant parts. People are more likely to help if they don't have to parse so much code.

Comment: please post less code, i think some codes on your post was not necessary

Comment: My apologies, i just am out of ideas and this is taking too much time....I just edited a part of the code i posted earlier.

Answer (score 0):

When you handle the event for the click of the page number in the control have a seperate function that updates both panels/controls with the data.

Comment: I tried this approach and did an UpdatePanel1.update() and UpdatePanel2.update() in the subscriber (aspx page) to the event and that did not work. the Event is implemeted as a delegate and the actions on the repeater are stored in an CustomEventArgs class and which is assigned a subscriber - which is where i did the update panel updates but no luck.

Comment: You might try this method - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12907075/updating-an-update-panel-in-a-usercontrol-from-a-control-in-another-user-control?rq=1